# I am not able to install steam on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies, steam

I followed the following steps
So first I confirmed that the multiverse Ubuntu repository is enabled:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
$ sudo apt update
```

and then I installed the steam package:

`$ sudo apt install steam`
and then I tried to execute the following command:

`$ steam`

and then;

````
   libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for user:``` 



I enter my password and then this appears:



```Steam needs to install these additional packages:
   libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for veer: 
..............
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libcrypt1:i386 (>= 1:4.4.10-10ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
libgl1:i386 : Depends: libglx0:i386 (= 1.3.1-1ubuntu0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libgcc-s1:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libllvm10:i386 (>= 1:9~svn298832-1~) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libstdc++6:i386 (>= 5.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Press return to continue:```


I press return and then after some time this appears
`You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
libgcc_s.so.1
libdrm.so.2`





I do not know what to do next. Please help
````

Comment: run `sudo apt install -f` to let apt try to resolve automatically. It also may yield hepful output on why *it is not going to be installed* that you may add to your question. If that is not working, check this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: Thank you a lot for answering but it does not work.

Comment: this :i386 is the whole problem, it seems to not work on 20.04 as trying to install :i386 pkgs ends up trying to remove even xorg sometimes! see if schroot works for you: https://askubuntu.com/a/1275742/589343, but I will just try SteamOS or ubuntu18.04 (that as I remember had good i386 support) on vmwareplayer (so I dont have to reboot).